# I have fewer relevant publications than I can highlight in my application

Tags: job, faculty-application

I am applying for a tenure-track position. I am allowed to add up to five particularly relevant publications. I have four first author papers and a bunch of more or less important co-authorships, nothing that directly relates to the topic of the position or were I am only one of many co-authors.
Should I just add something to the list, or stick with four papers?

A separate publication list is included.

Comment: Just don't give the idea that you have only four publications.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what would be an "irrelevant' publication when applying for a tenure track position. Even one in a completely different field might have relevance, I think.

Comment: @Buffy: I've known some people who would count a publication about teaching or pedagogy as a negative publication.

Comment: @user111388, can't tell you how sad that makes me.

Comment: @Buffy: Me too..

Answer (score 5):

I’d only add the four relevant ones, unless you have one that particularly speaks to your narrative about your research, etc.

The search committee can read your CV already. What they want is something they can grab onto and think about deeply, and generally I’ve found that “The applicant is a co-author in the middle of the paper” just gets it discounted.

Comment: *"just gets it discounted"* - that depends a lot on whoever is reviewing. In my circles having a deep network of collaborators is very, very important, and the best way to show this is having co-authored papers (good if they are with different people, best if your supervisor is not on the list).